# Do I need to set the default timezone for a Rails app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

A timepicker in my Rails app on Heroku, is showing the wrong time. It looks like it's showing the server time somehow. How should I correct this time? Do I need to configure my Rails app, or is there some setting on the Heroku server? The app will only be used in one timezone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In rails timezone can be set at config/application.rb. This works fine with development ENV and other servers like scaleway in production but not with heroku

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Europe/Paris'
end
```

For setting up the timezone in heroku you can set it from terminal

```
$ heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Paris"
```

Source https://coderwall.com/p/j9_e8a/set-timezone-for-your-heroku-app

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it still works with something like this from command line

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Chicago"
```

Comment: And how do I conifgure my rails app? Or is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default timezone in config/application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)